# Creating an SOM Hexagonal Map in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, som, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to create a SOM Hexagonal Map in R using the **[Kohonen Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kohonen/kohonen.pdf)**.

I've encountered a couple of problems while running this package. Sometimes I am receiving a message that says:

> "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    cannot take
>   a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'"

I receive this message although my sample is 1,000 observations and I use a 100x50 graph.

I am reproducing [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/self-organising-maps-for-customer-segmentation-using-r/) code but haven't been very successful.

Comment: Are you using the same dataset as given in the repository?

Comment: Hi! The sample dataset is a subset of the original dataset. The original dataset is of ~10,000 observations while the sample is of ~1,000. Ideally I would like to map all of the observations in a heatmap.

Comment: I tried reproducing the same code, it gave me an error `cannot create vector of size 998 mb`.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the Question. I'm starting with this  https://www.r-bloggers.com/self-organising-maps-for-customer-segmentation-using-r/ guide. The goal is to create https://github.com/geoss/som_visualization_r